# Dynamically setting target property in OSGi Reference annotatation

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, declarative-services

After reading an [article](https://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/set-osgi-service-reference-target-through-configuration/) on [Reference target](http://javadox.com/org.osgi/osgi.cmpn/6.0.0/org/osgi/service/component/annotations/Reference.html#target()) (and corresponding properties), I still don't understand how to retrieve a service, when `target` is set **at runtime** (typically target and properties are set at compile time and evaluated by SCR at runtime).

Let's say there are three service implementations defining`@Property(name="type", value="csv")`, `@Property(name="type", value="xls")` and `@Property(name="type", value="pdf")`, respectively.

And one consumer with:

```
//@Reference(target="(type=%runtime_variable%)")
Service service;
```

**NOTE** `%runtime_variable%` is automatically evaluated at runtime (read from a settings file).

---

Should I just call `getServiceReferences(Class<S> clazz, String filter)` in the `@Activate`/`@Modified` annotated method in order to get the right service at runtime?

How is the component.xml created, if I don't explicitly use `@Reference` and dynamically set the target in the `@Activate`/`@Modified` annotated method?

And can I use the[`@Designate`](http://javadox.com/org.osgi/osgi.cmpn/6.0.0/org/osgi/service/metatype/annotations/Designate.html) metatype annotation to make my life simpler here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That [article](https://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/set-osgi-service-reference-target-through-configuration/), you have read, is 7 year old and it is not clear to me which annotations it uses (yes, there are several). I'd suggest to ignore it. Today you better use [Declarative Services (DS)](https://enroute.osgi.org/FAQ/300-declarative-services.html) and the standard OSGi annotations.

In short there are 2 important pieces:

- XML files in `/OSGI-INF` folder inside the bundles providing / consuming services
- Service Component Runtime (SCR) - a bundle that inspects other bundles at runtime and if it finds the above XML files, takes care of registering and wiring the services.

While you can write the XML files by hand, they are typically generated by [Bnd](http://bnd.bndtools.org/) or other build tools using Bnd (such us [bnd-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/maven/bnd-maven-plugin)). This is done at build time when Bnd inspects your classes for annotations  and uses the information provided to generate the XML files. Thus the annotations are not used at all at runtime.

As for the wiring, when you have

```
   @Reference(target="(type=pdf)")
   Service service;
```

The field `service` will be automatically wired to one of the instances (yes there can be more than one) of `Service` service registered in OSGi's service registry that matches the target filter. This is done at runtime by SCR. You can change the target at runtime by reconfiguring your component using its PID. You can do that programmatically or via properties files using [Configuration Admin](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.cm.html).

The `@Designate` annotation you mentioned relates to another OSGi specification called Metatype. It allows you to better define the types of the configuration fields. [Here](http://njbartlett.name/2015/08/17/osgir6-declarative-services.html) you can read more about how to use Metatype together with Declarative Services 1.3.

Another good source of information regarding OSGi annotations is [here](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-osgi-annotations-what-they-are-and-when-to-use-them) (ignore the Liferay specific ones)

---

To reflect your edited question, you have some options. One is to get all instances:

```
@Reference(
 cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MULTIPLE,
 policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
 policyOption = ReferencePolicyOption.GREEDY
 )
protected void setService(Service service, Map<String, Object> properties) {
   String type = MapUtil.getString(properties, "type");
   _services.put(type, service);
}
```

Then you can get your service from `_services` map by type. Another is reconfigure your component. For example if you define it like this

```
@Component(
 configurationPid = "my.component"
)
public class MyComponent implements ... {
   @Reference(target="(type=pdf)")
   Service myService;
}
```

you can configure it via `my.component.cfg` in which you specify

```
myService.target=(type=somethingElse)
```

You can do the same programmatically using the Configuration Admin API.

Comment: I clarified the question in order for it to reflect more precise what my problem is. I know how to use SCR + annotations + maven. I want to set reference.target at runtime or sth. that is logically equivalent (in order to address specific customer needs by configuration of reference.target **without** recompiling).

Comment: Still, thanks for your answer and the interesting resources you did provide. I'll read through the links!

Comment: As I mentioned earlier annotations are processed at build time. Therefore

   `@Reference(target="(type=%runtime_variable%)")`
 
will never work. What you may use instead is get a list of all registered services and their metadata, keep them locally in some kind of map and use the one you need based on the runtime parameter.

Comment: What do I need for that? The `@Reference` in order for bnd to create the `component.xml` and a custom `@Activate` method which evaluates the services?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your updated question

Comment: Thanks! Where should I use the Configuration Admin API? In one big config bundle that does all the work and is started immediately?

Comment: That depends on the application and your business logic. Keep in mind in OSGi there is no guaranteed start ordering of bundles nor services. Therefore I'd recommend to use configuration file instead to not have to manually manage the whole lifecycle. Moreover from what you wrote "%runtime_variable% is automatically evaluated at runtime (read from a settings file)." this seams to be what you are already doing anyway. Why would you want to manually read a file then manually reconfigure when DS / ConfigAdmin can do that for you?

Comment: I did not depict the current state, rather the system-to-be. The product already has a settings infrastructure using files and a certain settings format (which the customer is already familiar with). The plan is to, at least try to, utilize that in order to simulate setting reference.target. I guess forcing a "configuration bundle" to load early seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: Try to get away from the idea that the configuration bundle (which could be an off-the-shelf solution like Felix File Install) needs to start really early. There is no need to insist on start ordering for OSGi bundles. Components will receive their configuration when it is ready.

Comment: DS link is dead, updated link: [https://enroute.osgi.org/FAQ/300-declarative-services.html](https://enroute.osgi.org/FAQ/300-declarative-services.html)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
@Reference
Service myService;
```

At runtime you then create a configuration for your component and set a filter like this:

```
myService.target=(mykey=1)
```

Comment: But how and where do I create a configuration at runtime? In the `@Activate`method?

Comment: Well a component does not configure itself. Normally the deployer will configure the system via Configuration Admin. So you would need to ensure a configuration under the PID of the component contains the desired target property and value.

Comment: The developed product is client software. Which is (re)started multiples times per day. This kind of configuration does not seam feasible. Would it be possible to write a component that starts immediately and performs the configuration?

Comment: There are several ways to configure the config admin. With felix fileinstall you can load configs from files. There is also the new felix configurator. It can load configs from json on startup. So you can make sure the config is present.

Comment: Configurations are persisted, so if the client is restarted then they will be automatically injected with the same configuration that they had before. It would be unusual to have a component which puts configuration for other components into configuration admin. Normally configurations are managed using a Configuration Management agent, which may use flat files (e.g. file install) or some more sophisticated mechanism (e.g. pushing data from a UI or database).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
@Property(name = "myService.target", label = "My Service", description = "The target reference for the MyService, e.g. use target=(type=html) to bind to services by type.")
@Reference(name = "myService")
private Service myService;
```

you can then create configuration file for you component `com.example.impl.MyComponent.config` :

```
myService.target="(type\=pdf)"
```

you could also change this value on runtime using Apache Felix Web Console (http://localhost:8888/system/console/configMgr).